# Select part of a string in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a query, and I am filtering out results by providing the query with information. I have the basic SELECT and then I have:

`AND db_schedules.daysofweek = '0'";`

However, this searches for the presence of 0 on it's own in the `daysofweek` column. How can I tell it to look for it in the string and not on it's own? Like if the column is something like 1340, then the query will return that record in the search result, because the query found a 0 in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `LIKE`:

```
AND db_schedules.daysofweek LIKE '%0%'";
```

Comment: I've made the LIKE into a `LIKE '%{$variable}%'` because I'd like for the variable to find the value input by the user in the select box. How can I assign a number to options in `<select>` so it gets generated in the `LIKE '%{$variable}%'`? Would something like `$variable = option box value` work?